# Python Multiply two arrays of unequal size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an amplitude curve from x = 2000 to 5000 in 3000 steps and a data curve from x = 0 to 10000 in 50000 steps. Now I want to normalize the data (multiply with the amplitude curve), but as you can see the two arrays are of unequal length and have different start points.

Is there any way of doing this without resizing one of the two? (all values outside the amplitude range can be zero)

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't want to resize the lists so you'll probably just have to iterate both lists using a while loop and keeping track of indices for each array. Stop looping when you reach the end of one the ranges.

You could also use the zip and map functions to do something like

```
>>> b = [2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> c = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> map( lambda x :  x[0]*x[1], zip(b, c[1:]))
>>> [6, 20, 42, 72]
```

but I am not sure if thats something you "can" do.

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize two arrays of unequal size, but you have to make a decision or two about what makes sense for your application.

Example code:

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4]
a2 = [20,30]
```

If I want to scale the values in a1 by a2, how should I do it?

- pairwise by indices, discarding extra length
- make copies of indices in a2 to pad its length
- pad values in a2 with fixed values
- interpolate values in a2 to create new data points, while adding to its length

Do what makes sense for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of do this with pandas if you're smart about how you define your row and column labels. When you multiply the dataframes, pandas will align the data where the column and row labels match. Values where the labels do not match will be set to NaN. Consider the following example:

```
# every other step
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3), 
    columns=[1, 3, 5], 
    index=[0, 2, 4]
)
print(df1)

   1  3  5
0  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
4  7  8  9

# every step
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=np.arange(0, 25).reshape(5, 5), 
    columns=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
)

    1   2   3   4   5
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24

print(df1 * df2)

     1   2    3   4    5
0    0  --    4  --   12  # <-- labels match
1   --  --   --  --   --
2   40  --   60  --   84  # <-- labels match
3   --  --   --  --   --
4  140  --  176  --  216  # <-- labels match
#   ^        ^        ^ 
#   |        |        |
```